# Geth Ropsten Syncing wrong Chain

Tags: go-ethereum, ropsten

I am trying to sync geth node with `--ropsten` CLI option and it completes syncing. But the latest blockchain number is different than ropsten.etherscan.io

The block number keeps incrementing and transactions are mined. I tried sending transactions from metamask wallet and it detected and mined the transaction. But the block that included the transaction is different than etherscan.

Maybe it's syncing a different work. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me two weeks to finally find the way to sync with main Ropsten blockchain, because all topic-related questions were outdated.

I run Geth as `geth --ropsten --cache=2048 --snapshot=false --syncmode=fast --whitelist 11356396=0xfbc4addc7d2ff815fb2f1025d2dd32b29db8d19af503dc9cb663830c65f49969`

Took my laptop one night to sync with the network and I have even successfully mined a block :)

The key part here is `--whitelist 11356396=0xfbc4addc7d2ff815fb2f1025d2dd32b29db8d19af503dc9cb663830c65f49969`. It means that all peers you want to connect to must have block `11356396` with hash `0xfbc4addc7d2ff815fb2f1025d2dd32b29db8d19af503dc9cb663830c65f49969`. You can leave that option as is or you can change it to your own, just take one of the latest block on https://ropsten.etherscan.io/ and copy its number and hash.

`snapshot=false` - I didn't want to waste time on snapshot generation. I'm not a specialist on blockchain and can't possibly say what is it and why do you need it (or not).

`--syncmode=fast` - I tried `full` sync mode before, it took 3 days to complete, but after I restarted the node, I wasn't able to connect to any peer. So I had to delete everything and start `fast` sync from scratch. With `fast` sync I always have about 10-13 peers.

`--cache=2048` - amount of memory for `fast` syncing, you might want to adjust it according to your resources

P.S. I saw your question while was in search for the same answers as you do and I hope that it helps and the question is still relevant for you.